# Showing tooltip value on mouse move on graph

Tags: java, user-interface, tooltip, jfreechart

I want to display tool-tip on mouse move on graph in the same way as it shows in reputation graph of the users in Stack Overflow.

How to display pointer on graph while showing tool-tip value?

Comment: I am using Chart panel and implemented Standard XY tooltip geneartor to standardXY itemrenderer

Comment: 1) What is stopping you from doing that? 2) Did you have a question?

Comment: Actually i want to show in such a way that on mouse move a pointer appear on line graph and it also move showing tooltipvalue on graphline.

Comment: yes i have asked the question and i am also able to show tooltip value but i want it to show in the format as it shows in reputaion graph of the users of this group

Comment: How to display pointer on graph while showing tooltip value?

Comment: I have edited the question back into the post (you can do that yourself) & deleted 2 of my comments (noise now).  But I still need an answer to *"1) What is stopping you from doing that?"*.  To expand on that:  What actual problem are you having?  What is the code (SSCCE) that is failing?  Without more specific information from you, it is unlikely this problem will be solved by us.

Comment: what should i do to display pointer on graph lines which moves on mouse move on graph? i dont know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

In your [`ChartFactory`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html), set the `tooltips` parameter to `true`. If you need additional help, please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: I am not using chartfactory instead i am using Chart panel and implemented Standard XY tooltip geneartor to standardXY itemrendererand also able to show tooltip value but i want to show in such a way that on mouse move a pointer appear on line graph and it also move showing tooltipvalue on graphline

Comment: Also set the crosshairs visible on the plot.